# Kill the command based on the `grep` output?

Tags: linux, process, kill

We have a command-line interface to logon to a system like so:

```
$ cli -u username -p password
```

In case if the wrong password is provided the message we get is " Credentials incorrect" and then it waits for the right password to be entered and doesn't quit. If the right password is provided, it doesn't provide any message and logs on directly.

I am looking to terminate the command in case the password is wrong, rather than waiting for the user input.

The idea is to look for the keyword Credentials and if it is found then kill the command:

```
$ cli -u username -p password | grep Credentials
```

How would I do that?

Comment: first, it is better to ask who provides this UI.but if you lunch this UI from regular Linux terminal, there are general keyword binding is Ctrl+D, Ctrl+C.

Comment: Are you trying to automate this, or do it manually?

Comment: Are `username` and `password` static strings, or uniquely entered by the user?

Comment: Are you looking for a wrapper around the `cli` command, or as Nick asked: something to clean these up after-the-fact?

Comment: FYI, providing a password as an argument on the command line is *a very bad idea.*

Comment: Do you do any kind of cmdline scrubbing in the script or will anyone who runs `ps aux` at the right moment see your credentials as long as the program is running?

Comment: duplicate of [Grep only the first match and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093452/grep-only-the-first-match-and-stop)

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

I modeled your `cli` utility like so:

```
$ cat cli
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [ "$line" == "password" ]; then
    break
  else
    echo 'Credentials incorrect'
  fi
done
```

#### Using `grep`

You can then use `grep -m1 ...` to break out after the first match is found. The `-m1` means stop after 1st match.

*bad password*

```
$ ./cli | grep -m 1 "Credential"
blah
Credentials incorrect

$
```

*good password*

```
$ ./cli | grep -m 1 "Credential"
password
$
```

#### Using `sed`

A similar approach use `sed`:

*bad password*

```
$ ./cli | sed '/Credential/ q'
blah
Credentials incorrect

$
```

*good password*

```
$ ./cli | sed '/Credential/ q'
password
$
```

Comment: The utility may be using standard error for messages to the user.

Comment: @Kusalananda - true, this can be adapted to that scenario by changing the `|` to a `|&`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than killing the process, you can check something like *[tries-before-disconnect](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/authentication-login-attempts-ssh-telnet-limiting.html)* in the config file. Which I usually do to restrict ssh login attempts.